# How can I change the text color of pop-up menu item

Tags: mobile, menu, colors, popupmenu

I have manually created a pop-up menu.
I have changed the items color to blue.

All the menu items have been changed to blue, except those ones which have been included manually.

How can I change those ones too?

Comment: Can you give us your code so we understand better?

Comment: I have added a header which contains a button. onClickListener for that button is:

`PopupMenu pop = new PopupMenu(Safe_Notes.this, v);  
    pop.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.safe__notes, pop.getMenu());
    pop.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener()
    {  
           public boolean onMenuItemClick (MenuItem item)
           {  
               if(item.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("set passcode"))
               {
                //code
               }

pop.show();`